# Can't Install DS Package in Delphi 5

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dspack

I have Windows 8 OS.

I am trying to install DS Pack component in Delphi 5 with reference to below link:

[Install DS Pack](https://snowyzone.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/how-to-install-delphi-7-and-dspack-2-3-4-in-windows-7/)

I have already take off ReadOnly access of Delphi5 folder where Delphi is installed.

After compiling DirectX9_D5.dpk and DSPack_D5.dpk, when I double click DSPackDesign_D5.dpk and Delphi IDE opens, I click on install button in the Package window. I get below eror message

Error No. 1:
The program can't start because DSPack_D5.bpl is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

once you click on OK button you get another below error message:

Error No. 2:
The program can't start because DSPack_D5.bpl is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

How to resolve this error?

With Best Regards.

Vishal

Comment: Check again if you followed installation guide properly. Most important is second node in DSP pack installation paragraph which tells you how to configure your library paths. And based on the fact that Delphi can't find needed .bpl means that you most likely screw something up when setting library paths.

Comment: If this person has their library path set correctly, it is also possible that they have not included the BPL paths in the windows PATH environment variable correctly.  DLLs can fail to load because of their dependency on other DLLs, which are in the same directory, when that directory is not in the PATH. This is a very common misunderstanding for developers who do know know what a DLL is, and how it works.

Comment: In my system, I see two Delphi paths, 1. C:\Users\Vishal Tiwari\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi5 and 2. C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi5. Any idea why these two paths ?

Comment: Read about application virtualization on MSDN. This came in with Vista 10 years ago. You should understand it by now. Simplest is to install Delphi to somewhere other than program files folder.

Comment: @David : Installing Delphi 5 to other folder location other than Program Files worked perfectly. Thanks a lot David.You Just ROCKSSSS !!!!!